# SSIS Convert Blank Datetime column to NULL and Parse Input

Tags: csv, datetime, ssis, etl, flat-file

I have the following simple SSIS Package to process a comma delimited file:

[image]

I'm having problems with date columns - specifically `MoveInDate` which the input column has data in the format `'20090731000000'`.

It goes into a database column `MoveInDt` which has a Datetime data type and data ends up in the format:

```
'2009-07-31 00:00:00.000'
```

In SSIS I have specified the input column to be `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`.  I'm unable to figure out how to do a simple 'if MoveInDate is blank, load null, else change data to 'YYYY-MM-DD 00:00:00.000'

Right now I can't even seem to figure out how to load a hardcoded date

This fails

[image: Derived Column]

As does

```
"2019-01-01"
```

Or

```
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)"2019-01-01"
(DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(DT_DATE)"2019-01-01"
```

> Error: 0xC02020A1 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [11]: Data conversion failed. The data conversion for column "Move In Date" returned status value 2 and status text "The value could not be converted because of a potential loss of data.".
>   Error: 0xC0209029 at Data Flow Task, Flat File Source [11]:

Looking up that message I've found posts about the data types not matching on the input to output column, but looking at it ...

Checking the flat file input column, it is defined as `DT_DBTIMESTAMP`

[image]

And the destination column is also defined as `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` when looking at input output properties.

[image]

I've looked at many questions here and elsewhere and have tried reducing the input to one simple row in the input file.  I've tried recreating the package several times.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the data is stored in the following format in the flat file

> 20090731000000

Then leave the source column data type as `DT_STR` and add a dervied column with the following expression:

```
(ISNULL([MoveInDate]) || [MoveInDate] == "") ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) : 
    (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)(LEFT([MoveInDate],4) + "-" + 
                     SUBSTRING([MoveInDate],5,2) + "-" + 
                     SUBSTRING([MoveInDate],7,2) + " " + 
                     SUBSTRING([MoveInDate],9,2) + ":" + 
                     SUBSTRING([MoveInDate],11,2) + ":" + 
                     SUBSTRING([MoveInDate],13,2) )
```

If data is stored in the following format:

> 2009-07-31 00:00:00

Use the following expression:

```
(ISNULL([MoveInDate]) || [MoveInDate] == "") 
         ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) 
         : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)[MoveInDate]
```

If data is stored in the following format:

> 2009-07-31

Use the following expression:

```
(ISNULL([MoveInDate]) || [MoveInDate] == "") 
         ? NULL(DT_DBTIMESTAMP) 
         : (DT_DBTIMESTAMP)([MoveInDate] + " 00:00:00")
```

Comment: I was finally able to verify that worked after working through some other load issues.  I'd be curious to know if it's even possible to load from DT_DBTIMESTAMP source datatype, but after spending so much time on this I'm just glad it worked.  Thanks - very useful.

Comment: @rigoo44 `20090731000000` cannot be implicitly converted to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` so setting the source column datatype to `DT_DBTIMESTAMP` will not work. if the column contains a value similar to `2009-07-31 00:00:00` it may works